# set of Kolmogorov-random strings is co-re

Tags: computability, semi-decidability, kolmogorov-complexity

given  R<sub>C</sub> = {x : C(x) ≥ |x|} is a set of  Kolmogorov-random strings.

How can I show that  R<sub>C</sub>  is co-re

I have been reading this paper [What Can be Efficiently Reduced to the
Kolmogorov-Random Strings?](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.5.4608&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which just says that we know that by Kum96 we know that R<sub>C</sub> is Co-re

I was not able to find the proof of how that is proved

Comment: Have you tried proving it yourself? Have you looked into Kum96?

Comment: What's "Kum96"?

Comment: @DavidRicherby, I would guess it likely is a reference to some other paper, from the paper linked in the question -- it is mentioned in the question.

Comment: one easy way to see that is that a string is compressible (or not algorithmicaly random, by defintion) if it is an output of a turing machine (=> computable) else it is algorithmicaly random (i.e incmpressible, non-computable)

Answer (score 7):

We want to show $\overline{R_c}\in RE$.

$\overline{R_c}=\left\{x|\exists M\hspace{1mm} s.t. \hspace{1mm} M(\epsilon)=x,|\langle M\rangle|<|x| \right\}$, i.e. $x$ is not a Kolmogorov-random string if there exists a Turing machine which outputs $x$ (say, when initialized with blank input), with description $\langle M\rangle$ shorter than $|x|$.

Given $x$, run all the Turing machines $M$ with description $|\langle M\rangle|<|x|$ with empty input $\epsilon$, simultaneously (i.e. dont execute any machine for $i+1$ steps before executing all of them for $i$ steps). This is possible since the set of all Turing machines of length $\le |x|$ is finite. If one of the machines halts and outputs $x$, accept, otherwise keep running. If all the machines halted with output different then $x$, reject.

Clearly if $x\in \overline{R_c}$ then our machine accepts, otherwise it either rejects or doesn't halt (which is the case if none of the machines outputs $x$ after some finite number of steps, and at least one of them doesn't halt).

Answer (score 2):

Not only is the set of [incompressible strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Compression) unrecognizable, *no* infinite set comprising of incompressible strings is Turing recognizable. Let's assume we could enumerate an infinite set of incompressible strings. Let the enumerator be $E$. Built a Turing machine $M$ ( $M$ disregards its input ) which first obtains its own description $\langle M \rangle $ by [recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem). Then it runs the enumerator $E$ and while enumerating the incompressible strings when it sees a string $s$ which is sufficiently longer than $\langle M \rangle $ ( sufficiently long depending on your method of encoding ), then $M$ prints $s$ and halts. This leads to a contradiction as $s$ turns out to be compressible, as it is outputted by $M$ where $\langle M \rangle  << |s|$. 
I misread the question,sorry for that. Anyways as Ariel has proved the set of incompressible strings is co-recognizable. And I have shown that the set is not recognizable, which also tells us that  the set is not decidable.